# Template 10: Hamburger menu keyboard shortcuts

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I am new in uwp app development. I made simple application based on Template 10 Hamburger template.I would like access hamburger menu item by keyboard shortcut. How is it possible?

I try use AccessKey, but HamburgerButtonInfo don't have this property, so I try:

```
    <Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo x:Name="SettingsButton" 
                                          PageParameter="0" 
                                          PageType="views:SettingsPage">
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AccessKey="D" >
                    <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                                Height="48"
                                Symbol="Setting" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,0,0,0"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="Settings" />
           </StackPanel>
     </Controls:HamburgerButtonInfo>
```

But result is exception with message: Catastrophic failure  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Radim

Comment: Try putting the accesskey on the textblock and handle the AccessKeyInvoked event of the textblock to navigate to the view

Comment: Yes, it is working! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As @KenTucker said:

> Try putting the accesskey on the textblock and handle the AccessKeyInvoked event of the textblock to navigate to the view.

I add this only so it can be marked as resolved.

Thank you for using Template 10.